# Capybara - unable to click a link

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd, capybara, bdd

I am using Capybara 2.4.4 to click a link.
The html is like this:

```
<a name="skiplink" id="skiplink" type="button" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="skipForm(); return false;">salta</a>
```

Capybara command:

```
find("a", :text => "salta").click
find('skiplink').click
```

none of both works:

```
Failure/Error: find("a", :text => "salta").click
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
```

I have copied-pasted the html from `save_and_open_page` output so it may be correct

I am using default driver (no selenium)

Thanks

Comment: If my answer below doesn't help please add the stack trace to the error so I can see where the error is coming from

Answer (score 8):

Either of the following should work

```
click_on('salta')
find(:css, '#skiplink').click   # the :css is only necessary if you've changed capybaras default selector
```

your find("a", :text => "salta").click should work too -- however when using capybaras default driver (racktest) clicking on javascript links isn't going to work since the driver doesn't support javascript.  You need to switch to a different driver (selenium, capybara-webkit, poltegeist, etc.) that supports javascript

Comment: That worked perfectly. What is the difference between `find('skiplink').click` and `find(:css, '#skiplink').click`?

Comment: find takes a few options, the first of which is a symbol determining what type of find to do -  If that symbol is left off it defaults to Capybara.default_selector - which defaults to :css -- the second option is then a css selector - so assuming Capybara.default_selector is :css find('skiplink') would try to find an element of type skiplink,  find('#skiplink') or find(:css,'#skiplink') would find an element with the id of skiplink   - there are many other types of finders see https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/selector.rb#L116 and you can add your own custom ones